# \r \n is not removed everywhere from php code

Tags: php

i have a sms script with php code where i have recived sms through sms portal. but in some message i have got \r and \n but on sms portal no special character like \r \n found

My message is like - NOKXX REG WMAH12345

but i have got this - NOKXX REG WMAH12345\r
                      NOKXX REG WMAH12345\n
                      NOKXX REG WMAH12345\n\n
                      NOKXX REG\RWMAH35907

i have got message from get method.............

```
$message = $_GET['message'];// Message content
```

i have tried this

```
$message=str_replace("\r\n","",$message);
```

and this as well

```
$message = trim($message);
// from everywhere
$message = str_replace("\n", "", $message);
$message = str_replace("\r", "", $message);
```

please suggest some alternate

Comment: The last code block should work. Do you actually see \r or \n if you echo it? If not, use single quotes instead.

Comment: i thave tried this as well, use single quotes but not working, i have NOKXX REGHELP\n\n\n

Comment: Try this: `$message = str_replace(array('\\n', '\\r'), array('', ''), $message);`

Comment: dear mark, no luck.... not working, just to inform you this is a sms based apps and i m sending sms to a particular number and from that server a url contanis sms value hit to my server

Comment: I realised it is an sms based app. Could you please do the following: `var_dump($_GET['message'])` and pastebin it?

Comment: dear mark, sorry i didn't understand pastebin? please ellabrate ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Xn3Az3ck   please check i have added as you said.

Comment: It does not really help me, as it is the code and not the data which causes the problem. This is why I asked you to provide me decent data (`var_dump($_GET['message'])`), because stackoverflow formats it. I cannot call this script with data, since I have no access to the data provider. (var_dump will output your data)

Comment: Even if this script is called by another server, you can put the value of `$_GET['message']` in a file, but without the actual content I can't really help you

Comment: dear mark, really thanks for your effort, but thing is that, this is the actual and only code. i can share the sms portal login password with you where i have mentioned this paticular page url (pastebin). and the $message varibale will get the format like | NOKXX<space>REG<space>Dealer code
NOKXX<space>REGHELP
etc etc in a message Variable,
now what happen is when i send a sms to xyz number with message NOKXX REGHELP and press enter button value comes in my table NOKXX REGHELP\n\n but the same thing i will do it from web or IOS phone everything works fine...

Comment: This might be some encoding related issue then, which depends on the sending client (since you said that it works from eg IOS). Try this before doing any replace `$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, "UTF-8");` (You must have mbstring installed) Also try the following (just for fun): `$message = explode('\n', $message)`. You should get an array. If not, then something really bad happens at you ;)

Comment: no mark.... ;( ;( .... web panel is working fine, IOS is working fine but when i use android or lumia phome SMS then \R comes with the SMS content and not replaced. ;(

Comment: This is what I exactly said. Did you try replacing \R instead of \r? it is not the same. Use the \\R form. Beyond this line, I am not sure how I could help you. As I said, without a pure paste of data, I cannot find out what the problem is. The only thing I can think about that the different clients (android, etc) sends messages in different encodings, this is what the mbstring is about, to convert it to UTF-8. Anyway, this work just fine for me http://codepad.org/myQ2SvJx

Answer (score 8):

Use single quotes, if your `\r` and `\n`'s are being treated as strings, so:

```
$message = str_replace(array('\n', '\r'), array('', ''), $message);
```

currently, your `str_replace` will look for actual line-breaks, not the string `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: boss i have tried this as well, but again \r and \n\n is comes into my table

Comment: if you're removing both, then you won't be getting any `\r` or `\n`. Create a pastebin.com with the original message (so stackoverflow doesn't remove the format).

Comment: why are you escaping the backslashes? `$message = str_replace(array('\\n', '\\r'), array('', ''), $message);` - just use what I gave you

Comment: Since the problem is that \n appears in the text, and not in the form of new line, it should be escaped. But there is something more here, as simply replacing the escaped form does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this...order is also imp

```
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: Dear sir, i have tried this as well, this is a sms based application, when i send message from my iphone then enter or space or special character is not comes, but when i use lumia phone or android to send sms with press enter then message comes with \n \r